# Selección de opción en Menú

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, html5

Deseo realizar un menú y que este contenga un `submenú` que al momento de escoger cada opción del submenu me muestre los datos que contenga cada opción, en un mismo `form`.

Ejm.

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="">A</a></li>
<li><a href="">B<a>
<ul>
<li><a href="">b1<a><li>
<li><a href="">b2<a><li>
<li><a href="">b3<a><li>
</ul>


<li>
<ul>
```

Al escojer b1 me muestre el contenido, ahi debo poner imágenes.
Por favor agradezco la ayuda ya que no tengo mucho conocimiento de ante mano gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo ver este ejemplo para la visualización de un menu desplegable, el cual te incluyo el codigo, necesitas conocimiento de CSS3 y HTML para adaptarlo a la necesidad de tu proyecto, modificar el estilo, colocar links, agregar y quitar menu/submenus;

link:

**https://desfaziendoentuertos.prepress.es/menu-desplegable-css/**

1) Ya habiendo configurado el menu te recomiendo crear un archivo **menu.css** para el estilo de este, el cual vas a usar en cada una de las paginas que seran enlazadas, de esta forma tienes acceso al menu en cada pagina.

Este lo incluiras de la siguiente forma en cada una de tus paginas dentro del bloque `<head>`

```
<link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

2) Crea un archivo **menu.php** y copia el contenido html del menu, el cual llamaras en las siguientes paginas de tus link **.php** con el comando `include'menu.php'` colocando debajo de la etiqueta body el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php 
  include 'menu.php';
?>
```

Aqui te incluyo el codigo de ejemplo para tu menu:

```css
/* menu */
#menu ul {
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

/* items del menu */
#menu ul li {
 background-color:#2e518b;
}

/* enlaces del menu */
#menu ul a {
 display:block;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:400;
 font-size:15px;
 padding:10px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 letter-spacing:1px;
}

/* items del menu */
#menu ul li {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

/* efecto al pasar el ratón por los items del menu */
#menu ul li:hover {
 background:#43ac23;
}


/* menu desplegable */
#menu ul ul {
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#eee;
 padding:0;
}

/* items del menu desplegable */
#menu ul ul li {
 float:none;
 width:150px
}

/* enlaces de los items del menu desplegable */
#menu ul ul a {
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px;
}

/* items del menu desplegable al pasar el ratón */

#menu ul li:hover > ul {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
 <!-- start nav -->
<nav id="menu">
    <!-- start menu -->
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Enlace A</a>
         <!-- start menu desplegable -->
         <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Enlace A.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Enlace A.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Enlace A.3</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!-- end menu desplegable -->
    </li>
     <li><a href="#">Enlace B</a>
            <!-- start menu desplegable -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Enlace B.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Enlace B.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Enlace B.3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- end menu desplegable -->
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Enlace C</a>
           <!-- start menu desplegable -->
           <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Enlace C.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Enlace C.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Enlace C.3</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!-- end menu desplegable -->
     </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end menu -->
    </nav>
    <!-- end nav -->
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]